# with_item and access array to pass separate value each time loop is executed

Tags: ansible

I have the following code and I am trying to figure out how I can pass each value from array access to the eos_config using iteration. I want to run the scripts eos_config only on all access port not routed.

```
- name: change description
  hosts: arista
  connection: local

  vars:
    access: []

  tasks:
    - name: show interface
      eos_command:
        commands: 
          - sh interfaces ethernet {{ item.if }} switchport | json
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
      with_items:
        - { if: '1'}
        - { if: '2'}
        - { if: '3'}
      register: showif

    - name: set access fact
      set_fact:
        access: "{{ access + [item] }}"
      with_items:
        - "{{showif.results[0].stdout[0].switchports.Ethernet1.enabled}}"
        - "{{showif.results[1].stdout[0].switchports.Ethernet2.enabled}}"
        - "{{showif.results[2].stdout[0].switchports.Ethernet3.enabled}}"
      when: '"mode" is defined'

    - debug: var=access

    - name: change description
      eos_config:
        lines:
          - description ansible_test
        parents: interface ethernet {{item.if}}
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
        authorize: yes
      with_items:
        - { if: '1' }
        - { if: '2' }
        - { if: '3' }
      when: 'access == true'
```

I am able to extract info about each port and assign true value if port is `access` or false when is `routed`.

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/arista.yaml:28
ok: [10.10.10.101] => {
    "access": [
        true, 
        true, 
        false
    ]
}
```

Now I would like to access this variable when running this part of code but don't know really how to do it.

```
  - name: change description
      eos_config:
        lines:
          - description ansible_test
        parents: interface ethernet {{item.if}}
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
        authorize: yes
      with_items:
        - { if: '1' }
        - { if: '2' }
        - { if: '3' }
      when: 'access == true'
```

I am getting following output for last part of the script:

```
TASK [change description] ******************************************************
task path: /etc/ansible/arista.yaml:30
skipping: [10.10.10.101] => (item={u'if': u'2'})  => {
    "changed": false, 
    "item": {
        "if": "2"
    }, 
    "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed", 
    "skipped": true
}
skipping: [10.10.10.101] => (item={u'if': u'1'})  => {
    "changed": false, 
    "item": {
        "if": "1"
    }, 
    "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed", 
    "skipped": true
}
skipping: [10.10.10.101] => (item={u'if': u'3'})  => {
    "changed": false, 
    "item": {
        "if": "3"
    }, 
    "skip_reason": "Conditional check failed", 
    "skipped": true
}
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this goal or what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this code as I have no access to eos device, but you can try the following logic using `with_together` to iterate over two lists simultaneously:

```
- name: change description
  hosts: arista
  connection: local

  vars:
    interfaces: ['1','2','3']

  tasks:
    - name: show interface
      eos_command:
        commands: 
          - sh interfaces ethernet {{ item }} switchport | json
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
      with_items: "{{ interfaces }}"
      register: showif

    - name: change description
      eos_config:
        lines:
          - description ansible_test
        parents: "interface ethernet {{ item.0 }}"
        provider: "{{ cli }}"
        authorize: yes
      when: item.1.stdout[0].switchports.Ethernet1.enabled
      with_together:
        - "{{ interfaces }}"
        - "{{ showif.results }}"
```

Comment: What guarantees here that the list elements will be processed in the correct order (and the same in both tasks, which would be required for the two lists to match)? In OP's transcript one list defined as "1, 2, 3" is processed as "2, 1, 3". It's likely they will, but is it certain?

Comment: You can check source code of `item` and `together` lookups, they never alter item order. I believe it is some kind of copy-paste issue in OP's transcript.